# java mysql count number of rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I created this code to allow me calculate the number of rows in my table. However, I'm not able to return the counted number with an error saying "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void." Could someone show me where' my error? Thanks alot!

```
public void num() throws Exception {
  try {
      // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?"
      + "user=root&password=");

      // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();
      resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from testdb.emg");
      int count = 0;
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
      }  
      return count;
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
```

Comment: Just as a side note: When you just want to count the number of rows, a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testdb.emg` is way more efficient

Comment: It seems you are missing a `}` a copy paste error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try below code

```
 public int num() throws Exception {
 try {
 // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 // Setup the connection with the DB
 connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?"
 + "user=root&password=");

 // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
 statement = connect.createStatement();
 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from testdb.emg");

 while (resultSet.next()) {
 return resultSet.getInt(1);
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Below were error

1. `public void num() throws Exception {`

   should be

   `public int num() throws Exception {`
2. For counting total rows you should use query `select count(*) from testdb.emg`

Let me know incase of any problem.

Answer (score 5):

How to get count(*) mysql data table in java.
TRY IT:

```
   public int getRowNumber(){

   int numberRow = 0;
   Connection mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USER_ID, PASSWORD);

try{
    mysqlConn.getConnection();
    String query = "select count(*) from dataTable";
    PreparedStatement st = mysqlConn.preparedStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        numberRow = rs.getInt("count(*)");
    }
}catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
return numberRow;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
public void num() throws Exception {
```

to

```
public int num() throws Exception {
```

You are returning value from variable `count` which is of type `int` therefore the return type of the method should be `int` as well.

You should also make sure there is a `return` statement in every execution path through your code including the exception handler in the `catch` blocks (or you will get a "missing return statement" error message). However, it is best to avoid `catch` statements which catch all exceptions (like yours). Also, ignoring (i.e. not handling) exceptions in the catch block often leads to hard to diagnose problems and is a bad practice.

There are also other problems with the code: with the exception of `count` none of your variables have been declared.

Note that you may use the following SQL statement to obtain the number of rows directly:

```
select count(*) from testdb.emg
```

This avoids sending all of the data from table `testdb.emg` to your application and is much faster for big tables.

Comment: I have change it, however, there's this message "missing return statement." I did put the return statement "return count;"

Comment: I've added explanation for this: you're not returning anything from the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void num() throws Exception {
```

should be

```
public int num() throws Exception {
```

Comment: I have change it, however, there's this message "missing return statement." I did put the return statement "return count;"

Comment: you have no return if an Exception is raised .. you can put a return statement in the Exception or put on under the Exception. Maybe you would use 0 or -1 in this case as return value

Answer (score 0):

I use Fahim Parker answer with a bit change

`

```
public int num() throws Exception {
 try {
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?"
 + "user=root&password=");

 statement = connect.createStatement();
 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("<your query statement>");

 resultSet.last(); //go to last row;
 return resultSet.getRow(); //get row number which is equal to rows count

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

`