# Control data in the database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

Good morning, I have a problem with a web application I'm creating. Premtto I'm quite new in this kind of programming.
So my web application should take care of booking hotel rooms. My problem is going to make a check when someone tries to book a room, so that you can not book two equal rooms in the same period.
Only that with the code written the check is not performed and the room is still booked. How could I do according to you? Thank you very much for your help.

```
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    //  out.println("driver loaded");
    Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "123456789");
    out.println("Connect");
    Statement  st = con.createStatement();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    out.println("connection successfull");

    String check = ("SELECT res1.id_prenotazione, res1.typeroom, res1.arrivaldate, res1.departuredate\n" +
        "FROM reservation res1, reservation res2\n" +
        "WHERE ( res1.typeroom = res2.typeroom ) \n" +
        "AND res1.id_prenotazione != res2.id_prenotazione\n" +
        "AND (res1.arrivaldate <= res2.departuredate)\n" +
        "AND (res2.arrivaldate <= res1.departuredate)");


    // ResultSet rs2  = stmt.executeQuery(check);
    out.println("<h1> Stringa chek eseguita </h1>");

    if (check) { // THIS DOESN't WORK OF COURSE
        int rs = st.executeUpdate("insert into reservation (login,email,typeroom,numroom,arrivaldate,departuredate)values ('" + login + "','" + email + "','" + typeroom + "','" + numroom + "','" + arrivaldate + "','" + departuredate + "')");
    }
    String getResultSet = ("SELECT count(*) FROM reservation WHERE arrivaldate ='" + arrivaldate + "'");
    String rs1 = ("SELECT count(*) FROM reservation WHERE arrivaldate");


    if (getResultSet != rs1) {
        int i = st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM reservation WHERE id_prenotazione ='" + id_prenotazione + "'");

    }
```

TABLE `reservation` (
    `id_prenotazione` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `typeroom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `numroom` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `arrivaldate` datetime NOT NULL,
    `departuredate` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_prenotazione`)

TABLE  `users` (
    `login` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`login`)

Comment: `if(check)` isn’t working... but `check` is a `String`? Do you not want a `boolean`?

Comment: @achAmháin I have tried also with boolean : Boolean check = (.....) != NULL and then IF (check) {... } But it is the same

Comment: Are you trying to execute a query with the check variable??

Comment: You've commented out the execute query just before the out.println() statement, thats why check will probably return false

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Yes i have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a join with the same table in your check SELECT but nothing has been inserted yet so the query is pointless. You need to check against the values for the reservation you want to store.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM reservation 
WHERE numroom = $roomnumber -- I am guessing numroom is room number
  AND ($startdate >= arrivaldate AND $startdate <= departuredate)
   OR ($enddate >= arrivaldate AND $enddate <= departuredate)
```

Replace the variables (`$...`) with your values. You might want to look into how to validate dates against each other, maybe it should be `<, >` rather than `<=, >=` in the comparison.

In Java this would be

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation WHERE numroom = '" + numroom + "' AND ('" + arrivaldate + "' >= arrivaldate AND '" + arrivaldate + "' <= departuredate) OR ('" + departuredate + "' >= arrivaldate AND '" + departuredate + "' <= departuredate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean with "your values"?

Comment: i don't have the variables because I insert them at the moment of booking

Comment: @Jack23 When you do the `INSERT` in your code you have the variables I am talking about, use them when checking if a reservation exists. I have updated the question

Comment: so you don't suggest to use Boolean but String, and what can i put in the if statement? if(query...)

Comment: You have to execute the query against the database of course and look at the result, if count > 0 then you already have a reservation

Comment: thank for your help,
I'm about to get the solution thanks to your help. If i put If( query == 0 ){ INSERT.... } I have an error because query  is a string.

Comment: @Jack23 See my previous comment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that "query" is a string. So if i do: String query = SELECT count(*).... , when i go to do if (query > 0 ) i can't do this.

Comment: I don't understand how can i do

Comment: @Jack23 You need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960681/9223839) with your query